# How to extract concrete values from defined options

Tags: isabelle

Is is possible when you call, say, `mapName(identifier)`, it returns something that is not '`rangeType option`', given that it's a finite map (finite domain and range) and you are sure that the identifier exists in the map?

Comment: If you have a map `map_name` of type `'a => 'b option` and know that `map_name id` will result in `Some x` for some `x` of type `'b`, then you can use `the :: 'a option => 'a` to extract `x` immediately, i.e., `the (map_name x)` will result in `x`.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you, Chris!

Comment: Okay, then I'll turn my comment into an answer, so that this question can be marked as answered for later visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering your question, let us make the kind of "partial functions" we are talking about precise.

(Explicitly) partial functions have type `'a => 'b option` in Isabelle/HOL. Then for every given `x :: 'a` such a partial function `f :: 'a => 'b option` results either in `None` (meaning that `f` is not defined on `x`) or `Some y :: 'b option` (whenever `f` actually is defined on `x`).

Now, if for some input `x` you know (which in Isabelle/HOL should mean that you have a proof for it) that `f x` is defined, you can employ the selector-function `the : 'a option => 'a` of the option type. So whenever `f x = Some y` then `the (f x)` results in `y`.

Note that in principle it is also possible to call `the None`. In that case we encounter a different kind of partial function that is available in Isabelle/HOL. The result of `the None` will still be of type `'b` but it is some arbitrary (and thus "undefined") value of that type `'b` of which we can prove virtually nothing.